# Ajax call doesn't give response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the login page i include a php file which looks like the following

**JS**

```
 <script>

var APP_URL = '<?= APP_URL?>';
function migrate(value){
    if(value==1) {
       $j.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: APP_URL+"corporate/secApi",
            data : {migration:1},
            success: function (rs) {
                console.log(rs);
                    alert("Migration Completed!\nEnjoy the new Goal feature");
                    $j("#fulldiv").remove();

            },
            failure: function () {
                alert("call to secApi failed!");
            }
        });
    }else{
        $j("#fulldiv").remove();
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="fulldiv">

<div id="dialog">
    <div id="dialog-bg">
        <div id="dialog-title">New Feature</div>
        <div id="dialog-description">EMarketeer has added new feature known as Goals, enabling this feature will allow you to set your own goals and keep the track of progress.</div>
        <div id="dialog-description" style="padding-top: 50px;">Would you like to Migrate to use new Goals feature?</div>

        <!-- Buttons, both options close the window in this demo -->
        <div id="dialog-buttons">
            <a href="javascript:migrate(1)" class="large green box">YES,  do it now!</a>
            <a href="javascript:migrate(0)" class="large red box">NO,  maybe  later</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['migration'])){
    $response = false;
    if($_POST['migration']==1) {
        $apiMgr = new SecureAPIClient((int)$_SESSION['id_user'], (int)$_SESSION['id_user_sub'], $ALLOWED_RESOURCES);
        $response = $apiMgr->migrateAccount($_SESSION['id_user']);
        if($response==true)
            echo 1;
        return;
    }
}
```

The call is made I can see the control comes the secApi.php upon completion nothing is consoled to the log. It worked before but only when i echo'd 1 instead of true and in success section of ajax call I had a check if(rs==1) dosomething but now not even that works. I just can't find the reason why.

Any suggestion please? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting IDs to everything? Why not use classes? Also, you shouldn't have more than one element with the same ID in the same page.

Comment: `failure` What's that???

Answer (score 0):

You should echo instead of return in PHP in order to get that value in client side.

```
<?php
   $response = false;
   if(isset($_POST['migration'])){

        if($_POST['migration']==1) {
            $apiMgr = new SecureAPIClient((int)$_SESSION['id_user'], (int)$_SESSION['id_user_sub'], $ALLOWED_RESOURCES);
            $response = $apiMgr->migrateAccount($_SESSION['id_user']);
        }
   }
   echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: There is more logic which echoes some other values. I am executing this piece of code on the specific condition. Thats why i was returning after echoing 1. Would that mean i should use exit when i want to stop the rest of the page to be executed?